# Typescript union of function signatures

Tags: typescript

Considering the following union of tuples:

```
type Test = 
  | ['a', (a: 'a') => void]
  | ['b', (b: 'b') => void]
```

Why would it be that function parameters cannot be inferred when using this type?

```
const test: Test = ['a', (a) => {}]
// Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

However, if I were **not** to use a union, the parameters will be inferred:

```
type Test = ['a', (a: 'a') => void]
const test: Test = ['a', (a) => {}]
// ✅
```

Comment: I think this is a missing feature specifically around discriminated unions of tuple types; see [ms/TS#42987](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42987) (which describes exactly this issue, but comes at it from a different angle).  Does that address your question fully? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in a comment if you reply so I'm notified)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript compiler is not perfect, it can't infer everything.

I can change your example so that it will work and it will not complain. Even though it is strange that your types guarantee that the function's input param will have an exact value.

Typescript playground  [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=41&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQOQEMUB9UCMUCh9RIoAVCAZ2AB5SoIAPYCAOwBMLZ4A%20JKAbVIAaKAAocALjIBKJLwBuAewCWbALoBuQgGNFLKlGZUp5KtXQpeyfhZGi0sxLwDeAXzVA)

```js
type Key = 'a'| 'b'

type Test<T extends Key> = [T, (b: T) => void];

const test: Test<'a'> = ['a', (a) => {}]
```